# Blazor Office Web Add-in Debugging not working

Tags: excel, office-js, blazor-webassembly, office-addins, excel-web-addins

I am unable to set the debugger breakpoint in Visual Studio on client-side C# and Razor code when launching Office Web Add-in. I have tried to manually attach various processes to VS debugger to no avail. Is this something that is currently possible?

I am using the following Microsoft's GitHub example to run Blazor Office Web Add-in for Excel:
[excel-blazor-add-in](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/blazor-add-in/excel-blazor-add-in)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. I was able to hit the breakpoints by attaching the debugger to the process where your code runs.

Note, you can also use the [Debugger.Break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.break?view=net-7.0) method which signals a breakpoint to an attached debugger. The following code example demonstrates how to stop the debugger at the call to `WriteLine`:

```
Debugger.Break();  
Console.WriteLine("Hello, world.");
```

If no debugger is attached, users are asked if they want to attach a debugger. If users say yes, the debugger is started. If a debugger is attached, the debugger is signaled with a user breakpoint event, and the debugger suspends execution of the process just as if a debugger breakpoint had been hit.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked

1. go to your sideloader project's user file .csproj.user and add the following lines in the PropertyGroup section, making sure you use the port number from your launchSettings.json

   ```
    <BlazorAppUrl>https://localhost:{portnumber for your https}/</BlazorAppUrl>

    <InspectUri>{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}</InspectUri>
   ```
2. navigate to the .vs hidden folder where your solution file is, close your solution and clear the contents in the .vs folder
3. Rebuild debug